# Justifying problem on index entries

Tags: indexing, makeindex, ragged2e

First an MWE and its output to the index page are as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[columns=2,columnsep=2em]

\begin{document}

This is it\index{important function important function important function}.

\index{many}

That's all!

\index{new}

OK! \index{very beautiful word involving only two letters}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the first index are not justifying. But if I move the `idxlayout` after the `imakeidx` package, the first index would be justifying:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\makeindex[columns=2,columnsep=2em]

\begin{document}

This is it\index{important function important function important function}.

\index{many}

That's all!

\index{new}

OK! \index{very beautiful word involving only two letters}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think there must be some conflict on index justification between the two packages, and so I go to the `idxlayout.dtx` file to see whether I could move the codes about index justification only after the `imakeidx` package. But unfortunately I failed, which may be due to my wrong ways in writing codes.

So is there a way to make the index entries justifying (i.e., make the index entries aligned both left and right sides as in picture 2), while the `idxlayout` package is still put before the `imakeidx` package since otherwise it will change some other settings in my file?

This question is also related to the one in [the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645964/140814).

Comment: Actually, I believe that both versions are ragged right, otherwise the interword spacing would almost surely be stretched.  It looks like the width of the line into which the entries are formatted is longer in the second version, but why that should be the case isn't obvious.  (I haven't looked at the code.)  But ragged setting can be checked by using some longer words in the middle of a long entry, to force different line breaks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I rewrite the codes and examples to make the problem more clear.

Comment: The package manual of `idxlayout`, sec. 2.3 _"Compatibility issues and notes"_ reads "Another package which must not be loaded after `idxlayout` is `imakeidx` which allows to create indexes during the main typesetting run." So I think this is a documented restriction.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Then I have to put `idxlayout` after `imakeidx` and I have to solve [another problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645964/140814) produced because of this.