# Index of Names and Index of Terms are not recognized as sections

Tags: sectioning, indexing

First an MWE and its output to the contents and index pages are as follows.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[totoc=true]{idxlayout}

\indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section,noclearpage}
\makeindex[name=name,title=Index of Names,options=-s mystyle2.ist]
\makeindex[title=Index of Terms]


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}

This is it\index{important function important function important function}.

\index{many}

That's all, Legend Green! \index[name]{Green, Legend}

\index{new}

OK! \index{very beautiful word involving only two letters}

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\chapter*{Indices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indices}

\printindex[name]

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you see, "Index of Names" and "Index of Terms" are as chapters in the pdf while I want them to be as sections of "Indices". So I set

```
\indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section,noclearpage}
```

but it doesn't work.

So is there any way to make "Index of Names" and "Index of Terms" be as sections invoking `imakeidx` before`idxlayout` according to the documentation of `idxlayout` (see also [the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645898/140814))?

Comment: Just don't use `idxlayout` and add the `intoc` option to `\makeindex`

Comment: @egreg But I have to use the `idxlayout` package to set something which couldn't be set by the `imakeidx` package, for example, `initsep`, `hangindent`, `subsubindent`, and to solve the problem in [the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645898/140814).

Comment: Well, the two packages fight each other in redefining `theindex`. And `idxlayout` doesn't offer the possibility to set the level.

Comment: @egreg Do you have any idea to the problem in  [the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645898/140814)? If so we can solve the problem as above by putting the `idxlayout` package before the `imakeidx` package and using `intoc`. This means, we need to solve only one of the two problems.

Comment: No, that won't work.

Comment: @egreg I tried that and it indeed worked. This may be because they all have their own ways to set the chapter or section title styles for index, and the one who comes late works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `idxlayout` doesn't offer the possibility to set the level and once you use it the relevant options in `\indexsetup` are useless.

Dirty trick: locally undefine `\chapter`, so `idxlayout` will use `\section*`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[totoc=true]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[name=name,title=Index of Names]%,options=-s mystyle2.ist]
\makeindex[title=Index of Terms]
\indexsetup{noclearpage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

This is it\index{important function important function important function}.

\index{many}

That's all, Legend Green! \index[name]{Green, Legend}

\index{new}

OK! \index{very beautiful word involving only two letters}

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\chapter*{Indices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indices}

% dirty trick starts
\begingroup
\let\chapter\relax

\printindex[name]

\printindex
\endgroup
% dirty trick ends

\end{document}
```

#### Table of contents

[image]

#### Indices

[image]

Comment: Aha, I've ever tried `\indexsetup{othercode={\let\chapter\relax}}` but it doesn't work. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this one is easier than [Justifying problem on index entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645898).

```tex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\ila@prologue
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\indexname}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\xpatchcmd\ila@prologue
  {\chapter*}
  {\section*}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
```

Full example

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[totoc=true]{idxlayout}

\indexsetup{toclevel=section,noclearpage}
\makeindex[name=name,title=Index of Names,options=-s mystyle2.ist]
\makeindex[title=Index of Terms]

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\ila@prologue
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\indexname}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\xpatchcmd\ila@prologue
  {\chapter*}
  {\section*}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}

This is it\index{important function important function important function}.

\index{many}

That's all, Legend Green! \index[name]{Green, Legend}

\index{new}

OK! \index{very beautiful word involving only two letters}

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\chapter*{Indices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indices}

\printindex[name]

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Compiled on Overleaf.com, texlive2021

[image: toc part]
[image: indices part]

Comment: While the print lists are still in the chapter style. So maybe some more codes needs to be replaced?

Comment: @M.Logic Answer updated. thank you

Comment: @M.Logic It seems "It looks like" is just an informal form of "it seems as if" https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/it-looks-like .

Comment: I could accept only one answer, and according to the order I accpet @egreg 's, but I vote you once.